# iAd Banner being hidden behind keyboard, is this an issue?- swift

Tags: swift, iad

I have an ad banner inside the view of the TabBarController in my app so that it's always positioned above the tabBar on any viewcontroller and is always visible. In one viewcontroller the use opens up the keyboard breifly to fill in some text fields - would this be an issue when it comes to apple reviewing my binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing…

I don't think it's Apple's interpretation of a good UI if they force you to have the Ad visible during editing a field. In worst case it would look like a (weird) accessoryView to the keyboard and kind of 'tricks' users to tap on it – which is again a bad UX.

So this would make me think you are perfectly fine with hiding the Ad or let it be covered by your input view during edit.

Comment: my thoughts exactly, makes me feel a lot more confident that someone agrees, thank you.